# Prove that all terms of a sequence of functions are convex.

Tags: derivatives, convex-analysis

Let 
$\ f_{n}: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R, \quad  f_{n}(x) = \left(e^{x}\right)^{1/n}.$ 
Is there a natural $n$ such that $f_{n}$ is concave on $[0,1]$?

So second derivative is
$$\left(\left(e^{x}\right)^{1/n}\right)'' = 
\left(\frac{1}{n}\left(e^{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}-1}\!\!\cdot e^{x}\right)' = 
\left(\frac{1}{n}\left(e^{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)' = 
\frac{1}{n^2}\left(e^{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}  $$

$e^{x} > 0 $ for every $x\in[0,1]$, so $\dfrac{1}{n^2}\left(e^{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} > 0$ for every $n \in \mathbb N$.

Summing up, second derivative is greater then $0$ for $x\in[0,1]$ and $n \in \mathbb N$ so $f_{n}$ are convex for any $n \in \mathbb N$.

Is this prove correct?

Comment: It's okay. Since $(e^x)^{1/n}= e^{x/n}$ your calculation of the second derivative can be shortened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes That is O.K. It is enough to prove that $(e^x)^{\frac{1}{n}}$  is convex not only for $x\in [0,1]$ but also for $x\in \mathbb{R}$. And then you above  question has this answer"$f_n $is never be concave."